# How to generete the right story source code for custom rendered Vue 3 stories in storybook?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, storybook

Here are some examples of my expectations, which seem to be impossible to accomplish with storybook:

**Example 1**

```js
export const Story1 = {
  args: { label: "ButtonLabel" },
  render: (args) => ({
    components: { MyButton },
    setup() {
        return {args}
    },
    template: `<MyButton>{{args.label}}</MyButton>`,
  }),
};
```

Expected Output:

```html
<MyButton>ButtonLabel</MyButton>
```

Actual Output:

```html
<MyButton />
```

**Example 2**

```js
export const Story2 = {
  args: { label: "ButtonLabel" },
  render: (args) => ({
    components: { MyButton },
    setup() {
        return {args}
    },
    template: `<div><MyButton v-for="count in 3" :key="count">{{args.label}}</MyButton></div>`,
  }),
};
```

Expected Output:

```html
<div>
 <MyButton>ButtonLabel</MyButton>
 <MyButton>ButtonLabel</MyButton>
 <MyButton>ButtonLabel</MyButton>
<div>
```

Actual Output:

```html
<MyButton v-for="k in 3" key="k" />
```

I am aware, that you can fully customize the source code output with `parameters.docs.source.code` or `parameters.docs.source.transform`. However, I don't know how I can produce the expected outputs. Is there a library that can do exactly what I need here?

> NOTE: The rendered output is correct. Just the source code that is produced is wrong.

Comment: It's unknown what's your setup and why this `render:` property is there, but it's probably not a problem here. If you have a specific story in mind, you can extract the whole thing to story component, so template would have only `<MyStory v-bind="args"/>`.

Comment: `render` is included in the new Storybook v7 format. The point here is, that you sometimes want to have 1 story showing all different versions of a Button for example. Creating a new component, wouldn't make sense here.

Comment: Good to know. It makes sense the same way as it makes sense to have comps as SFC instead of writing them inline, since Vue allows both. This allows to separate story config from presentation. Had a similar case and story comps could be simple but quite lengthy ones. Still not sure if this can help here